# How to set the RichTextBox.SelectionFont FontFamily without changing the Style?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to set `RichTextBox.SelectionFont` FontFamily without changing the Style
because my font doesn't support Bold and Regular style.

```
rtb.SelectionFont = New Font(New FontFamily(nicknamefonttype), nicknamefontsize, 0, GraphicsUnit.Point)
```

It is giving an error that the font does not support bold and regular.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this in my WPF application to apply a `System.Drawing.FontFamily` to my selected text:

```
rtb.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(FontFamilyProperty, ((System.Drawing.FontFamily)rbngFonts.SelectedItem).Name);
```

The rbngFonts is a RibbonGallery, so I suspect you need to adapt it to your application.